# Get Enum Name or Description from enum value stored in Datatable

Tags: c#, generics, enums, datatables

I have an enum like this for a bank master table (column name: `BankAccountType`)

```
public enum eBankAccountType
{
    Savings = 1,
    Current = 2,
    CC = 3,
    Other = 4,
 }
```

And I am storing enum values in one table database for every row.

Now at the time of getting records from the database, I am returning this enum values only. But how should I write a generic method in C# which accepts

- Datatable (which is return from database select query)
- ColumnName(s) (with values e.g. 1,2,etc which is retrieved from table Bank, In this Case 'BankAccountType') and
- EnumType(s) (to which I would Like to convert this column value in a Enum String e.g if `BankAccountType == 1` then `Savings`, `BankAccountType == 2` then `Current` and so on)

And Returns a datatable with having a new column added for each row(in this case 'BankAccountTypeDescription')

Please note that datatable returned from database can have more than one columns which are populated from different Enums.

I am able to do it if I use any static enum type, but I would like to create more of a generalized method.

I am trying to create a generic method something like this.

```
public DataTable GetDescriptionforEnumColumn(DataTable dt, Enum[] objEnum, string[] colName)
{

    foreach (string item in colName)
    {
        string strIDColumnName = item;
        string strNewColumnName = item + "Description";
        dt.Columns.Add(strNewColumnName);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row[strNewColumnName] = Enum.Parse(objEnum[0].GetType(), ConvertTo.String(row[item]), true);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

And Call it like this.

```
GetDescriptionforEnumColumn(dtBank, array of enum, array of columNames);
```

But I am having issues is passing and retrieving enum (or type of enum) array in this generic method.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? what is your first attempt to write such a generic method?

Comment: Presumably you started writing a method that took a `DataTable` and column name and an enum type; how did it go? where did you get stuck? Also: *why* do people still insist on using `DataTable`?

Comment: Updated the question with what I have tried till now.

Comment: @MarcGravell, you are right about not using datatables, but the project I am working on is years old asp .net with datatables only. so it will be  huge task to convert it to List or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private DataTable GetDescriptionForEnumColumn(DataTable dt, dynamic columnsInfo)
    {
        foreach (var item in columnsInfo)
        {
            string strIDColumnName = item.IDColumnName;
            string strNewColumnName = item.IDColumnName + "Description";
            Enum columnEnumName = item.ColumnType;

            dt.Columns.Add(strNewColumnName);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if ((ConvertTo.Integer(row[strIDColumnName]) > 0))
                    row[strNewColumnName] = SystemEnum.GetEnumDescriptionFromString(Enum.Parse(columnEnumName.GetType(), ConvertTo.String(row[strIDColumnName]), true).ToString(), columnEnumName.GetType());
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

and calling it like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetDescriptionForEnumColumn(dtBank, new[] { new { ColumnType = (Enum)new eBankAccountType(), IDColumnName = "BankAccountType" } });
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it your main problem is how to get the value `Savings` when you have only a `1` and make it general for all types of enums.

If my assumption is correct, then the [Enum.ToObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject(v=vs.110).aspx) method is your friend:

```
public static string convertEnum(int intValue, Type enumType) 
{
    return Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue).ToString();
}
```

To make this method a little more secure, you can check whether the `intValue` is defined at all in this enum-type using the [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public static string convertEnum(int value, Type enumType) 
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong call mate! gimme somthing to work with...");
    }

    return Enum.ToObject(enumType, value).ToString();
}
```

I guess with this knowledge you should be able to write the rest of the method yourself. Good fortune